# Failed to pull "/system/bin/sh: readlink - QtCreator bug workaround?

Tags: android, c++, qt-creator

I'm supposed to develop an android app using QtCreator in C++. QtCreator is, however, very user unfriendly and permanently confronts me with bugs and errors that I did not cause and do not understand. I'm still in the phase if building plain new project. The error that occurs when I build it is:

```
The process "C:/Qt/android.5.5.1/5.5/android_armv7/bin/androiddeployqt.exe" exited normally.
Pulling files necessary for debugging.
Package deploy: Running command "C:/Users/username/AppData/Local/Android/android-sdk/platform-tools/adb.exe -s 520592f0406021ce pull /system/bin/sh: readlink: not found D:/projects/build-androidtest-Android_for_armeabi_v7a_GCC_4_9_Qt_5_5_1-Debug/app_process".
Packaging error: Command "C:/Users/username/AppData/Local/Android/android-sdk/platform-tools/adb.exe -s 520592f0406021ce pull /system/bin/sh: readlink: not found D:/projects/build-androidtest-Android_for_armeabi_v7a_GCC_4_9_Qt_5_5_1-Debug/app_process" failed.Exit code: 1
Package deploy: Failed to pull "/system/bin/sh: readlink: not found" to "D:/projects/build-androidtest-Android_for_armeabi_v7a_GCC_4_9_Qt_5_5_1-Debug/app_process".
```

I have a suspicion that a piece of unix oriented code propagated into Windows version of QtCreator. It's **[a reported bug marked as fixed](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTCREATORBUG-14201)**, but not in any released version, so I need to get it to work anyway.

Any ideas? I mean, is there actually anyone who uses Qt C++ android librarie in QtCreator on Windows? Because google searches are not very helpful on these topics.

Comment: Are you sure you have a working Android SDK and haven't miss any file in it?

Comment: @MasihAkbari I'm sure it's a reported bug that doesn't happen in new unstable releases. But unstable releases are not what I want to use in production environment.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Well it seems this is Qt creator bug to connect and debug the app you can try using qt libraries with visual studio and debug your application with VS.

**UPDATE**
it's a little bit hard but you can find the full process of doing that in [here](http://visualgdb.com/tutorials/android/qt/)

Comment: Does Visual studio support compiling for android?

Comment: Also, refering as well to your wrong edit, this **IS A QTCREATOR ISSUE**, not Android SDK or Qt library issue.

Comment: @TomášZato ok,sorry for my wront edit, i updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks, that looks really very interesting.

Comment: @TomášZato i'm glad, hope you enjoy the buggy land of QT. :)

Comment: VS solution is not applicable in my case. What about http://download.qt.io/development_releases/qtcreator/3.6/3.6.0-beta1/ - have anyone tried this version? I installed this on top of existing Qt installation but could not manage to add Android "kit" to it, it does not auto-detect like in previous Qt Creators.